# Is it possible to specify the column list for an INSERT statement in the SELECT statement?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have to produce a dynamically generated T-SQL script that inserts records into various tables.   I've done a bunch of searching and testing but can't seem to find the path I'm looking for.

I know that the following is valid SQL:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ( [Col1], [Col2], [Col3] )
SELECT N'Val1', N'Val2', N'Val3';
```

But, is it at all possible to write something akin to this:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable]
SELECT [Col1] = N'Val1', [Col2] = N'Val2', [Col3] = N'Val3';
```

By having the columns in the select statement, I'm able to do it all at once vs writing 2 separate lines.  Obviously my idea doesn't work, I'm trying to figure out whether something similar is possible or I need to stick with the first one.

Much appreciated.

Comment: You need to stick with the first approach - the column list must be explicitly specified in the `INSERT` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice for `insert` statements is to specify the columns list in the `insert` clause, and for very good reasons:

1. It's far more readable. You know exactly what value goes into what column.
2. You don't have to provide values to nullable \ default valued columns.
3. You're not bound to the order of the columns in the table.
4. In case a column is added to the table, your insert statement might not break (It will if the newly added column is not nullable and doesn't have a default value).
5. In some cases, SQL Server demands you specify the columns list explicitly, like when `identity_insert` is set to `on`.

And in any case, the column names or aliases in the `select` clause of the `insert...select` statement does not have any effect as to what target columns the value column should go to. values are directed to target based only on their location in the statement.